# What's the name of the algorithm concerning daily planner rendering?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Is there a *well-known algorithm* that is able to take as input **a collection of time-bound items**  (defined by a *start time* and *an end time*) and produce **a "graphical" layout**? By *graphical* I mean a bi-dimensional projection of those events (2d matrix, 2d space boundaries, whatever).

The output has to be *bi-dimensional* because the input may contain overlapping events (events beginning at the same time etc.). One dimension would be *the time*, of course, and the other one is an *artificial* one.

If we associate a vertical axis **y** with the time dimension and a horizontal one, **x**, with the *artificial dimension*, then I am thinking about an algorithm playing with X and Y tokens, about token *requirements* and tokens *availability*.

E.g. the algorithm used by *Outlook* to render the daily view of the calendar etc.

Thank you!

PS: I believe the term "projection" is not correct, because we are **adding** an artificial dimension :)

PPS: Maybe what I want is one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aScheduling_algorithms)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These slides: http://www.cs.illinois.edu/class/fa07/cs473ug/Lectures/lecture2.pdf call that "interval partitioning" (second part of the slides - haven't found another reference to that term elsewhere) and give a proof that a greedy algorithm works: sort the items by start time; when processing an item, if you can put it in one of the "bins" already there, put it there, otherwise start a new bin and put the item there.

Comment: Thank you a lot, @Balise :) I am leaving this question open for at least one more day, though.

Comment: Now the more interesting question would be - what to do for "online" interval partitioning, i.e. instead of having one list at the beginning of the algorithm, you get items one by one. Obviously you can re-sort/re-organize everything that you got until now, but it's ugly, and I'm not sure it's a good idea, GUI-wise, to reshuffle everything when you add an appointment. So the objective function may not even be the same in that case...